# How to Whitelist AWS IPs Across Resource Types

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have a bare metal IBM server running a SQL Server database. We also have a wide variety of AWS services (EC2, lambda, API Gateway) in different accounts/regions that need access to the database. Is there any possible way to white list AWS IPs across services without VPC? Obviously you can find the AWS IP ranges, but there are 100s of them, so maintaining the list would be a nightmare. Is there any way to simplify this?

Comment: Not in any meaningful way. Think about it - if you whitelisted all the blocks that EC2 uses, sure your instances could get in, but so could a good half the servers on the internet.

Comment: You should consider using a VPC and a VPN between your VPC and your bare metal server. Whitelisting all AWS IP-ranges is like whitelisting half of the internet, so there's not much benefit from doing so. Instead with a VPN you're independent of AWS public IP-ranges and even get an additional layer of encryption on top of it.

Comment: Look at Transit Gateway... It says to your “on-prem” network, but it can really be anywhere you can make that VPN connection https://aws.amazon.com/transit-gateway/

Answer (score 0):

The comments to my question above indicate the real answer to me question, which is simply, "no". They do provide meaningful alternatives, so I am going to consider this question closed.